# Asp.Net MVC 4 - Changes to cshtml file requires a rebuild

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have added mobile views to my MVC 4 project as _Layout.Mobile.cshtml and Index.Mobile.cshtml. The problem seems like if I make a change to .cshtml file I am required to rebuild the project otherwise the desktop view is rendered. Also Sometimes I have correct mobile layout view with desktop index view rendered.

After rebuild all works fine.

NB: I am using razorGenerator for pre-compiled views.

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: It's possible that the rebuild is just forcing something (probably IIS) to clear a cache...

Comment: I think so but not sure why? Is there something I am missing on the configuration for mobile views.